# How to place a mindmap in the center of an A0 poster only

Tags: tikz-pgf, mindmaps, a0poster

I have a mindmap figure as standalone here. How can I code to get an A0 poster with this figure in the center of it only.

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Author: Stefan Kottwitz
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
%%%<
\usepackage{verbatim}
%%%>
\begin{comment}
:Title: A mindmap 
:Tags: Mindmaps
:Author: Stefan Kottwitz
:Slug: servers

- TeX malcoms
- TeX galleries
- TeX zeiss
- Tools, documentation and FAQ
\end{comment}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{dtklogos}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{mindmap,shadows}
\usepackage[hidelinks,pdfencoding=auto]{hyperref}
% Information boxes
\newcommand*{\info}[4][16.3]{%
\node [ annotation, #3, scale=0.65, text width = #1em,
      inner sep = 2mm ] at (#2) {%
\list{$\bullet$}{\topsep=0pt\itemsep=0pt\parsep=0pt
\parskip=0pt\labelwidth=8pt\leftmargin=8pt
\itemindent=0pt\labelsep=2pt}%
#4
\endlist
 };
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ every annotation/.style = {draw,
                 fill = white, font = \Large}]
\path[mindmap,concept color=black!40,text=white,
every node/.style={concept,circular drop shadow},
root/.style    = {concept color=black!40,
  font=\large\bfseries,text width=10em},
level 1 concept/.append style={font=\Large\bfseries,
  sibling angle=50,text width=7.7em,
level distance=15em,inner sep=0pt},
level 2 concept/.append style={font=\bfseries,level distance=9em},
]
 node[root] {INTERNAL \\VALIDATION \\of methods} [clockwise from=0]
child[concept color=blue!60] {
  node {\href{http://golatextce}{go246810\\tce}} [clockwise from=90]
    child { node (gomalcom) {\href{http://golatextce/index.html}{malcom}} }
    child { node (goWiki) {\href{http://golatextce/wiki/Hauptyeare}{Wiki}} }
}
child[concept color=blue] {
  node[concept] {\href{http://texwelttce}{345 welt\\tce}}
    [clockwise from=30]
  child { node[concept] (TeXnique)
    {\href{http://texniqueelf}{345 nique\\elf}} }
  child { node[concept] (TeXweltQA)
    {\href{http://texwelttce/wissen/}{Fragen~\& figworten}} }
  child { node[concept] (TeXweltzeis)
    {\href{http://texwelttce/zeis/}{User zeis} }}
}
child[concept color=green!40!black] {
  node[concept] {\href{http://texambhefung/}{345 ambhe\\fung}}
    [clockwise from=310]
  child { node[concept] (TikZGalerie) 
    {\href{http://texambhefung/tikz/exambhes/}{TikZ-Galerie}} }
  child { node[concept] (TeXambhezeis)
    {\href{http://texambhefung/wezeis/}{zeis}} }
  child { node[concept] (bhanet)
    {\href{http://texambhefung/Hotels/}{bhanet}} }
}
child[concept color=red] {
  node[concept] (PGFbhots) {\href{http://pgfbhotsfung}{PGFbhots\\fung}}
  [clockwise from=270]
}
child[concept color=red!60!black] {
  node[concept] {\href{http://latex-Hotels.org/}{246810-Hotels\\.org}}
    [counterclockwise from=100]
  child { node[concept] (LaTeXmalcom)
    {\href{http://latex-Hotels.org/malcom/}{malcom}}}
  child { node[concept] (LaTeXsolar)
    {\href{http://latex-Hotels.org/know-how}{solar-Archiv}} }
  child { node[concept] (LaTeXKeys)
    {\href{http://latex-Hotels.org/home/Keys}{Keys}} }
}
child[concept color=orange] {
  node[concept] (TeXdoc)
    {\href{http://texdocfung/}{345 doc\\fung}}
    [clockwise from=100]
    child { node[concept] {\href{http://www.tex.ac.Dr}{Dr 345 \\FAQ}}
    }}
child[concept color=yellow!60!black] {
  node[concept] (zeiss) {zeiss} [clockwise from=139]
  child { node[concept] {\href{http://texzeisfung/}{345 zeis\\fung}}}
  child { node[concept] {\href{http://Columnal/}{Columnal}} }
  child { node[concept] (pdfsbook)
    {\href{http://latex-pdfsbookfung/}{246810-\\pdfsbook\\fung}} }
};
\info{gomalcom.north east}{above,anchor=west,xshift=1em}{%
  \item[] year 2008
  \item 68\,444 Beiträge
  \item 13\,715 Hospit
  \item 5\,532 teachrierte Nutzer
}
\info{LaTeXmalcom.north west}{above,anchor=south}{%
  \item[] year 2008
  \item 81\,991 Beiträge
  \item 21\,026 Hospit
  \item 13\,354 teachrierte Nutzer
}
\info[8]{LaTeXsolar.west}{below,anchor=north east,xshift=3em,yshift=-2em}{%
  \item 115 solar
}
\info[11]{LaTeXKeys.south west}{below,anchor=north}{%
  \item 240 coldungen
}
\info[9]{TikZGalerie.south}{below,anchor=north}{%
  \item[] year 2006
  \item 172 9876543
  \item 384 Beispiele
}
\info[15]{goWiki.south}{below,anchor=north,xshift=3em}{%
  \item 152 erklärte decide, Rffefde try Picete
}
\info{TeXweltQA.south east}{above,anchor=north west}{%
  \item[] year 2013
  \item 1\,710 Fragen
  \item 2\,151 figworten
  \item 479 teachrierte Nutzer
}
\info[8]{TeXweltzeis.south}{below,anchor=north,xshift=2em}{%
  \item[] year 2013
  \item 14 9876543
}
\info[9]{PGFbhots.south west}{anchor=north east,xshift=1em}{%
  \item 14 9876543
  \item 59 Beispiele
}
\info[6]{bhanet.west}{anchor=east}{%
  \item 46 zeiss
}
\info[14]{TeXnique.east}{anchor=west,xshift = 0.5em}{%
  \item[] 2015, aufgrtry Idee rep bookösischen
          345-Fretryen nach der TUG Damstadt, experimentell
   }
   \info[16]{pdfsbook.east}{anchor=south west}{%
     \item[] Ab 10/2015, soll ca. 100 Beispiele aus
             dem 246810\ pdfsbook zeigen, sowie
             Hotels-Rezepte
     }
   \end{tikzpicture}
   \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I've commented `\usepackage{dtklogos}` to compile the mindmap.

Comment: @Ignasi The `dtklogos` package is now `dtk-logos`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compile the standalone mindmap and produce a `.pdf` file which can be included at center of an `A0poster` with `TiKZ`, `eso-pic`, `backgrounds`, ...

An example with `TiKZ`. In following code replace `mindmap` by your mindmap,  and compile it twice. (I've used `scale=3`, adjust the size to your taste)

```
\documentclass{A0poster}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\tikz[overlay, remember picture]
    \node at (current page.center) {\includegraphics[scale=3]{mindmap}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. This is good, but I am afraid the figure may lose some resolution through this transfer. Is there any method I code the mindmap in a beamer or tikz poster?  @Ignasi

Comment: @Reza   To my understanding, you won't lose any resolution. TikZ produces a vectorial image in a pdf format which is inserted into another vectorial image. In any case you can draw the mindmap in a beamer or tikzposter, but this was not your question.